# Looking for one regex to replace my string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem with regex and need some help.
Current I have url has type 
`/search/:year/:month/:day/xxxx` with `:month` and `:day` maybe exist or not . Now I need replace `/search/:year/:month/:day` patern on my url with empty string. Meaning get remain of url part. So this is some example below

1.'/search/2017/02/03/category/gun' => '/category/gun'

2.'/search/2017/02/03/' => '/'

3.'/search/2017/01/category/gun' => '/category/gun/'

4.'/search/2017/category/gun/' => '/category/gun/'

5.'/search/2018/?category=gun&type%5B%5D=sendo' => '/?category=gun&type%5B%5D=sendo/'

I try to use regex = `/^\/search\/((?:\d{4}))(?:\/((?:\d|1[012]|0[1-9])))?(?:\/((?:[0-3]\d)))/`

But it is failed for case `/search/2017/category/gun/`

```
const regex = /^\/search\/((?:\d{4}))(?:\/((?:\d|1[012]|0[1-9])))?(?:\/((?:[0-3]\d)))/
const testLink = [
  '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/01/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun/',
  '/search/2018/?category=gun&type%5B%5D=sendo'

]

testLink.forEach((value, i) => {
  console.log(value.replace(regex, ''))
  console.log('-------------------')
})
```

Comment: Your 3rd output ends with slash (/) whereas your 4th output does not. Any reason why?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I've just update my question. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex pattern `(\/search\/.*\d+)(?=\/)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LBkSR/4)**

```js
const regex = /(\/search\/.*\d+)(?=\/)/g;
const testLink = [
  '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/01/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/',
  '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun/',
  '/search/2018/?category=gun&type%5B%5D=sendo'
]

testLink.forEach((value, i) => {
  console.log(value.replace(regex, ''))
  console.log('-------------------')
})
```

Comment: Sorry But I've just update my question, your code not work for my case `/search/2018/?category=gun&type%5B%5D=sendo`

Comment: It fail other case except `/?category=gun&type%5B%5D=sendo` is right

Comment: sorry.now check this new one

Comment: Thank you so much. I think your regex is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting on the following pattern seems to work:

```
\d{4}(?:/\d{2})*
```

This would place the target you want as the second element in the split array, with the first portion being what precedes the year-digit portions of the path.

```js
input = '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun';
parts = input.split(/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})*/);
console.log(parts[1]);
console.log('/search/2017/02/03'.split(/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})*/)[1]);
console.log('/search/2017/01/category/gun'.split(/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})*/)[1]);
console.log('/search/2017/category/gun/'.split(/\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})*/)[1]);
```

Whether you do or do not expect a final trailing path separator is not entirely clear.  In any case, the above answered can be modified per that expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
strings = [
    '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun',
    '/search/2017/02/03/',
    '/search/2017/01/category/gun',
    '/search/2017/category/gun/',
]; for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    alert(strings[i].replace(/\/search\/[0-9\/]+(\/)(category\/[^\/$]+)?.*/,'$1$2'));
}
```

Comment: Thank for your comment but I am looking for a regex to resolve all case

Comment: Can you please explain what about my answer is wrong?

Comment: It seem to be fail with case 

/search/2018/?gender=1&user-age=37&category=gun&type=tomoko

Comment: @Bình Trương It resolves all cases that were present when I wrote it. I’m not incredibly motivated to constantly revise for you.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen If you have an answer I’ve had nothing to do with it. If you’re asking as a favor, I can check later, but likely someone else will have informed you by then.

Comment: Year sorry for my question isnt complete, but thank you for your support me .

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same regex but revers the order of this part `(?:\d|1[012]|0[1-9])`
 as following `(?:\d|1[012]|0[1-9])` and make last group optional as following `((?:[0-3]\d)))?`

```
const regex = /^\/search\/((?:\d{4}))(?:\/((?:0[1-9]|1[012]|\d)))?(?:\/((?:[0-3]\d)))?/
const testLink = [
  '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/01/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/category/gun/',
  '/search/2017/02/03/category/gun/'
]
```

> output
>
> ### /category/gun/
>
> ### /category/gun/
>
> ### /category/gun/
>
> ### /category/gun/

if you are sure of date format so you can simplify your exp to be `^\/search\/\d{4}(?:\/\d{1,2}){0,2}`

Comment: Thank for your support me. It seem this is other good answer.